# Head Style Native Webbrowser Control MSAccess 2013

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, webbrowser-control, stylesheet

I'm storing some **html strings** in a **memo field** in a table database built in **Microsoft Access** 2013 x64.

I'm showing those html strings in a **Native WebBrowser control** (Access 2010/2013).

I want to apply simple **formatting** (font family, font size, etc) to those html documents using the **style element** of the **head** section of the document.

I **have tried** the following:

Firstly I tried adding the head section directly in my **string**:

```
' strModified is just the body of a modified html document.

strModified = "<HTML><HEAD><style> " & _
              "html *{" & _
              "font-family:Calibri !important;" & _
              "font-size: 20pt !important;" & _
              "} " & _
              "</style></HEAD>" & strModified & "</HTML>"
```

Next I tried creating directly the **style node** in the head. I succeeded in that but didn't find a way for passing the **innerText** to it:

```
Dim html        As HTMLDocument
Dim elc         As HTMLHtmlElement
Set html = Me.WebBrowser2.Object.Document
    With html
        Set elc = .createElement("style")
'        elc.innerText = "html *{ " & _
                        "font-family:Calibri !important;" & _
                        "font-size: 9pt !important" & _
                        "}"
        .Head.appendChild elc
    End With
Set html = Nothing
```

Finally I tried setting the head style every time the displayed **document change**:

```
Private Sub cboDescriptions_AfterUpdate()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblDescriptions")
    With rst
        .Index = "PrimaryKey"
        .Seek "=", Me.cboDescriptions
        Dim html As HTMLDocument
        Set html = Me.WebBrowser2.Object.Document
            With html
                Do While .ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Loop
                .Head.Style.fontFamily = "Verdana"
                .Head.Style.FontSize = 20
                .body.innerHTML = rst.Fields(2)
            End With
        Set html = Nothing
    End With
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

I would like to ask how to add **head styles** to **html strings** to be displayed in a **WebBrowser Control** (native or ActiveX) in **MsAccess**

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I decided to use the ActiveX WebBrowser control instead of the native WebBrowser for Access 2010/2013 since the former accepts the html string and formats the document correctly by using the write property of the document.

```
With Me.WebBrowser6.Object
    .Navigate2 "about:blank"
    .Document.write rst.Fields(2)
    .Refresh
End With
```